# Changing Transition Timing of a CodePen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I really like the  CodePen linked [here](https://codepen.io/dev_loop/pen/MWKbJmO), and would like to incorporate it into a personal project I'm working on, however I don't know JS and want to change the fly-in effect. I just want the entire transition to fade into view as soon as the webpage loads. Is there any way anyone could help me do this?

```
console.clear();

const { gsap, imagesLoaded } = window;

const buttons = {
    prev: document.querySelector(".btn--left"),
    next: document.querySelector(".btn--right"),
};
const cardsContainerEl = document.querySelector(".cards__wrapper");
const appBgContainerEl = document.querySelector(".app__bg");

const cardInfosContainerEl = document.querySelector(".info__wrapper");

buttons.next.addEventListener("click", () => swapCards("right"));

buttons.prev.addEventListener("click", () => swapCards("left"));

function swapCards(direction) {
    const currentCardEl = cardsContainerEl.querySelector(".current--card");
    const previousCardEl = cardsContainerEl.querySelector(".previous--card");
    const nextCardEl = cardsContainerEl.querySelector(".next--card");

    const currentBgImageEl = appBgContainerEl.querySelector(".current--image");
    const previousBgImageEl = appBgContainerEl.querySelector(".previous--image");
    const nextBgImageEl = appBgContainerEl.querySelector(".next--image");

    changeInfo(direction);
    swapCardsClass();

    removeCardEvents(currentCardEl);

    function swapCardsClass() {
        currentCardEl.classList.remove("current--card");
        previousCardEl.classList.remove("previous--card");
        nextCardEl.classList.remove("next--card");

        currentBgImageEl.classList.remove("current--image");
        previousBgImageEl.classList.remove("previous--image");
        nextBgImageEl.classList.remove("next--image");

        currentCardEl.style.zIndex = "50";
        currentBgImageEl.style.zIndex = "-2";

        if (direction === "right") {
            previousCardEl.style.zIndex = "20";
            nextCardEl.style.zIndex = "30";

            nextBgImageEl.style.zIndex = "-1";

            currentCardEl.classList.add("previous--card");
            previousCardEl.classList.add("next--card");
            nextCardEl.classList.add("current--card");

            currentBgImageEl.classList.add("previous--image");
            previousBgImageEl.classList.add("next--image");
            nextBgImageEl.classList.add("current--image");
        } else if (direction === "left") {
            previousCardEl.style.zIndex = "30";
            nextCardEl.style.zIndex = "20";

            previousBgImageEl.style.zIndex = "-1";

            currentCardEl.classList.add("next--card");
            previousCardEl.classList.add("current--card");
            nextCardEl.classList.add("previous--card");

            currentBgImageEl.classList.add("next--image");
            previousBgImageEl.classList.add("current--image");
            nextBgImageEl.classList.add("previous--image");
        }
    }
}

function changeInfo(direction) {
    let currentInfoEl = cardInfosContainerEl.querySelector(".current--info");
    let previousInfoEl = cardInfosContainerEl.querySelector(".previous--info");
    let nextInfoEl = cardInfosContainerEl.querySelector(".next--info");

    gsap.timeline()
        .to([buttons.prev, buttons.next], {
        duration: 0.2,
        opacity: 0.5,
        pointerEvents: "none",
    })
        .to(
        currentInfoEl.querySelectorAll(".text"),
        {
            duration: 0.4,
            stagger: 0.1,
            translateY: "-120px",
            opacity: 0,
        },
        "-="
    )
        .call(() => {
        swapInfosClass(direction);
    })
        .call(() => initCardEvents())
        .fromTo(
        direction === "right"
        ? nextInfoEl.querySelectorAll(".text")
        : previousInfoEl.querySelectorAll(".text"),
        {
            opacity: 0,
            translateY: "40px",
        },
        {
            duration: 0.4,
            stagger: 0.1,
            translateY: "0px",
            opacity: 1,
        }
    )
        .to([buttons.prev, buttons.next], {
        duration: 0.2,
        opacity: 1,
        pointerEvents: "all",
    });

    function swapInfosClass() {
        currentInfoEl.classList.remove("current--info");
        previousInfoEl.classList.remove("previous--info");
        nextInfoEl.classList.remove("next--info");

        if (direction === "right") {
            currentInfoEl.classList.add("previous--info");
            nextInfoEl.classList.add("current--info");
            previousInfoEl.classList.add("next--info");
        } else if (direction === "left") {
            currentInfoEl.classList.add("next--info");
            nextInfoEl.classList.add("previous--info");
            previousInfoEl.classList.add("current--info");
        }
    }
}

function updateCard(e) {
    const card = e.currentTarget;
    const box = card.getBoundingClientRect();
    const centerPosition = {
        x: box.left + box.width / 2,
        y: box.top + box.height / 2,
    };
    let angle = Math.atan2(e.pageX - centerPosition.x, 0) * (35 / Math.PI);
    gsap.set(card, {
        "--current-card-rotation-offset": `${angle}deg`,
    });
    const currentInfoEl = cardInfosContainerEl.querySelector(".current--info");
    gsap.set(currentInfoEl, {
        rotateY: `${angle}deg`,
    });
}

function resetCardTransforms(e) {
    const card = e.currentTarget;
    const currentInfoEl = cardInfosContainerEl.querySelector(".current--info");
    gsap.set(card, {
        "--current-card-rotation-offset": 0,
    });
    gsap.set(currentInfoEl, {
        rotateY: 0,
    });
}

function initCardEvents() {
    const currentCardEl = cardsContainerEl.querySelector(".current--card");
    currentCardEl.addEventListener("pointermove", updateCard);
    currentCardEl.addEventListener("pointerout", (e) => {
        resetCardTransforms(e);
    });
}

initCardEvents();

function removeCardEvents(card) {
    card.removeEventListener("pointermove", updateCard);
}

function init() {

    let tl = gsap.timeline();

    tl.to(cardsContainerEl.children, {
        delay: 0.15,
        duration: 0.5,
        stagger: {
            ease: "power4.inOut",
            from: "right",
            amount: 0.1,
        },
        "--card-translateY-offset": "0%",
    })
        .to(cardInfosContainerEl.querySelector(".current--info").querySelectorAll(".text"), {
        delay: 0.5,
        duration: 0.4,
        stagger: 0.1,
        opacity: 1,
        translateY: 0,
    })
        .to(
        [buttons.prev, buttons.next],
        {
            duration: 0.4,
            opacity: 1,
            pointerEvents: "all",
        },
        "-=0.4"
    );
}

const waitForImages = () => {
    const images = [...document.querySelectorAll("img")];
    const totalImages = images.length;
    let loadedImages = 0;
    const loaderEl = document.querySelector(".loader span");

    gsap.set(cardsContainerEl.children, {
        "--card-translateY-offset": "100vh",
    });
    gsap.set(cardInfosContainerEl.querySelector(".current--info").querySelectorAll(".text"), {
        translateY: "40px",
        opacity: 0,
    });
    gsap.set([buttons.prev, buttons.next], {
        pointerEvents: "none",
        opacity: "0",
    });

    images.forEach((image) => {
        imagesLoaded(image, (instance) => {
            if (instance.isComplete) {
                loadedImages++;
                let loadProgress = loadedImages / totalImages;

                gsap.to(loaderEl, {
                    duration: 1,
                    scaleX: loadProgress,
                    backgroundColor: `hsl(${loadProgress * 120}, 100%, 50%`,
                });

                if (totalImages == loadedImages) {
                    gsap.timeline()
                        .to(".loading__wrapper", {
                        duration: 0.8,
                        opacity: 0,
                        pointerEvents: "none",
                    })
                        .call(() => init());
                }
            }
        });
    });
};

waitForImages();
```

Here's the code I'm working with. I have tried altering the --card-transition-duration variable to less than 800ms, but this doesn't seem to have the effect that I want since it is used so often throughout the entire CodePen.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by "the entire transition"?

Comment: in the pen you linked `function init()` in line:179 in `js` is what you need,but why are you asking double question,do you want to reduce transition time or animate the entire card holder?